# ¿Cómo se puede insertar en SQL los valores no repetidos?

Tags: sql

Tengo 2 tablas con los mismos campos, utilizo Sql server 2008

- tabla1 `(id,rfc,nombrepersona)` //registros 300
- tabla2 `(id,rfc,nombrepersona)` //registros 0

  id   int; llave
  rfc  char(13);
  nomprepersona varchar(50);

¿Cómo puedo insertar en la tabla2 aquellos registros cuyo rfc no esté repetido en la tabla1?

Ya que en tabla1 hay bastantes rfc repetidos con el mismo nombre de persona pero con diferente id.

```
id//    //rfc//   //nombrepersonal//
 1  ACA7505204U6  nombre1
 2  ACA810623DE7  nombre2
 3  ACA890206MD6  nombre3
 4  ACA890206MD6  nombre4
```

Intento con ésto:

```
insert into tabla2(id,rfc,nombrepersona) select id,rfc,nombrepersona from tabla2 where id not in(select id from tabla1)
```

Comment: Bienvenido para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: Hola Begginer, sería bueno que agregases algo más de información, como por ejemplo, la base de datos que estés usando o lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento (junto a los errores/problemas que te esté dando). Te recomiendo lee [ask] y completar el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: Tambien, vas a tener que aclarar cual de todos los datos de los otros campos queres pasar para un rfc repetido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, lo haré

Comment: @gbianchi esto se solucionaria con un campo unique en rfc??

Comment: @LuisFernando no sabria contestarte eso.. no se cuales son sus reglas.

Comment: @gbianchi a ver si pone sus reglas.

Comment: Por qué primero no haces una consulta **distinct** a tu  campo rfc, y aplicas tu inserción con los registros resultante.

Answer (score 1):

Si te da igual que nombrepersona traerte, podrías hacer algo tipo

```
INSERT INTO tabla2 (id, rfc, nombrepersona)
SELECT id, rfc, nombrepersona from tabla1 where id in (select id from tabla1 where rfc in (select distinct rfc from tabla1))
```

Recuerda, antes de hacer el insert into, es muy recomendable que pruebes el select individualmente y si publicas más detalles podemos ayudarte más exactamente en lo que buscas!

Y si el id es autoinc, no lo añadas en las consultas!

Answer (score 1):

Estuve revisando este tema y entre las respuestas creo que ya te respondieron pero parece que le falto hacer una prueba o que nos dijeras que resultado tuvo la solución planteada, en fin, creo que con estos arreglos queda:

```
INSERT INTO into tabla2 (id,rfc,nombrepersona) 
SELECT id,rfc,nombrepersona 
FROM tabla1 
WHERE rfc IN (SELECT rfc 
                FROM tabla1 
                GROUP BY rfc 
                HAVING count(rfc) = 1);
```

Con esto te llevas todos los rfc´s que no estén repetidos, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, no especificas tipos de datos, sistema gestor de bases de datos que usas, etc.

Lo siguiente, lo he probado en postgresql 8.4 y funciona:

```
insert into tabla2 (id,rfc,nombrepersona) 
select id,rfc,nombrepersona from tabla1 where rfc in (select rfc from tabla1 group by rfc having count(rfc) = 1 limit 1)
```

En el having count(rfc) = 1, el 1 dice la cantidad de veces que rfc debe estar presente en tabla1 para tenerlo en cuenta.
Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero si no especifica nada de eso, es preferible esperar a que lo haga. E igual, vos estas seguro que si un rfc se repite, le va a traer alguno de esos? porque justamente lo que pide es traerlos todos pero que no esten repetidos. y tu query solo trae los que estan una sola vez.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no he podido resolver el problema, espero me puedan ayudar utilizo sql server